# Remove duplicates based on specific criteria

Tags: r, duplicates

I have a dataset that looks something like this:

```
df <- structure(list(Claim.Num = c(500L, 500L, 600L, 600L, 700L, 700L, 
100L, 200L, 300L), Amount = c(NA, 1000L, NA, 564L, 0L, 200L, 
NA, 0L, NA), Company = structure(c(NA, 1L, NA, 4L, 2L, 3L, NA, 
3L, NA), .Label = c("ATT", "Boeing", "Petco", "T Mobile"), class = "factor")), .Names =     
c("Claim.Num", "Amount", "Company"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

I want to remove duplicate rows based on Claim Num values, but to remove duplicates based on the following criteria: `df$Company == 'NA' | df$Amount == 0`

In other words, remove records 1, 3, and 5.

I've gotten this far: `df <- df[!duplicated(df$Claim.Num[which(df$Amount = 0 | df$Company == 'NA')]),]`

The code runs without errors, but doesn't actually remove duplicate rows based on the required criteria. I think that's because I'm telling it to remove any duplicate Claim Nums which match to those criteria, but not to remove any duplicate `Claim.Num` but treat certain Amounts & Companies preferentially for removal. Please note that, I can't simple filter out the dataset based on specified values, as there are other records that may have 0 or NA values, that require inclusion (e.g. records 8 & 9 shouldn't be excluded because their Claim.Nums are not duplicated).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you order your data frame first, then you can make sure `duplicated` keeps the ones you want:

```
df.tmp <- with(df, df[order(ifelse(is.na(Company) | Amount == 0, 1, 0)), ])
df.tmp[!duplicated(df.tmp$Claim.Num), ]
#   Claim.Num Amount  Company
# 2       500   1000      ATT
# 4       600    564 T Mobile
# 6       700    200    Petco
# 7       100     NA     <NA>
# 8       200      0    Petco
# 9       300     NA     <NA>
```

Comment: This works on the example data, but what if there's an additional row `# 10      700    100    MyCo` which has the same Claim.Num but doesn't have 0 for Amount or NA for Company.  (Easy fix, of course.)

Comment: That worked. @BrodieG can you briefly explain the principle behind first ordering then removing duplicates? And the `0,1,0` for ordering amount? I'm sorry i'm not very familiar w/ the `duplicated` function yet.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg my particular dataset doesn't have duplicates outside of the stated criteria, but very interested to see how you would deal w/ that situation for future operations like this.

Comment: @DaNiu, `duplicated` will return the indices of all elements that are duplicates after the first one.  By making sure that the ones you want to remove are not first (i.e. by ordering), we can keep the other ones.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different approach

```
r <- merge(df,
           aggregate(df$Amount,by=list(Claim.Num=df$Claim.Num),length),
           by="Claim.Num")
result <-r[!(r$x>1 & (is.na(r$Company) | (r$Amount==0))),-ncol(r)]
result
#   Claim.Num Amount  Company
# 1       100     NA     <NA>
# 2       200      0    Petco
# 3       300     NA     <NA>
# 5       500   1000      ATT
# 7       600    564 T Mobile
# 9       700    200    Petco
```

This adds a column `x` to indicate which rows have `Claim.Num` present more than once, then filters the result based on your criteria. The use of `-ncol(r)` just removes the column `x` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Another way based on `subset` and logical indices:

```
subset(dat, !(duplicated(Claim.Num) | duplicated(Claim.Num, fromLast = TRUE)) |  
         (!is.na(Amount) & Amount))

  Claim.Num Amount  Company
2       500   1000      ATT
4       600    564 T Mobile
6       700    200    Petco
7       100     NA     <NA>
8       200      0    Petco
9       300     NA     <NA>
```